IntelliJ + maven : does not recompile automatically sub modules
I have this app loaded in IntelliJ: all modules projects sources are loaded + the "acme-lib" projects too.
<modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>app</module>
</modules>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>acme-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${acme.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-lib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-lib2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

The app module contains the Main class.
If I modify the sources of acme-lib, I need to launch manually the lifecycle maven install otherwise, the modifications are not taken when I launch the App with IntelliJ
Worse, If I modify the sources of service, again, I need to launch manually the lifecycle  maven install otherwise, the modifications are not taken when I launch the App with IntelliJ.
The auto-build is activated.
Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven is activated
In the 'Launch' configuration, "Do not build before run" is checked, otherwise it compile everything and it takes time!
How to make IntelliJ more automatic and avoid to run the lifecycle "install" every time?

NOTE: If I use Eclipse, I have to trouble, it build projects
automatically and it's much faster.

Thanks!
PS: it's IntelliJ Community 2024.1.1

What's the value of ${acme.version}? This should end in -SNAPSHOT

Yes, all versions end in -SNAPSHOT .. End actually:
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version> ..   <acme.version>${project.version}</acme.version>

The current behavior you're describing is regular Maven logic, Maven only works on the basis of Artifacts (JARs), so it does require mvn install to run to account for changes made to the code.
IDEA can account for the code changes "on the fly" (without mvn install), but in order to get it working you have to make sure that:

All Projects are added to the same IDEA window (you can check that
via Maven Tool Window) and have explicitly defined dependencies between them via Artifacts Coordinates.
"Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" option is disabled.
You run your Apps using Application Run Configurations.

